# Using css instead of table functions in html

Tags: html, css

How is it possible to place a list in the center of the page. In html you could create a table and do it with for example a table width of 100% and then you could devide each section. But I want to get rid of that and want to focus more on my css. I created a div and my css for the list looks like this at the moment:

```
.list {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 6em;
        background: white;
        position: absolute;
        height: auto;
        border: 1px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        -border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
}
```

**Edit:** I already created an unordered list and tagged it in a div with the class name "list" I just want to know how I can put the list in the middle of the site. **I am sorry** for not being explicit enough.

Comment: Make sure your `.list` has `display: block`

Comment: Remove `position: absolute` and it will be centered. [Try it here](http://jsfiddle.net/KAXHV/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS looks fine, simply remove `position: absolute;` from it and it will be centered perfectly:

**CSS**

```
.list {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 6em;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

You can use the shorthand notation for margins here like that: `margin: 0 auto;`. This means, that the top and bottom margins are set to `0` and left and right are set to `auto`.

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/u4vhc/)

Answer (score 0):

Look into the css display:table sets. something like http://ajaxian.com/archives/display-table

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `<ul>` list and apply css. This is what something i've recently been working on

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7DS4L/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should sort you out: http://jsfiddle.net/hYFgp/

HTML

```
<ul>
<li>#1</li>
<li>#2</li>
<li>#3</li>
<li>#4</li>
<li>#5</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul{
width: 200px;
border: 1px solid red;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
}
ul li{
text-align: center;
list-style-type: none;
}
```

Then fiddle around with the styles to get it looking exactly how you want it to . . .

Comment: You'll find, with HTML + CSS there will be many ways to achieve the same results. Not all are correct, not all are valid code and not all are seen as 'best practice' . . .